# kendo mobile listview filterable, return always first records

Tags: listview, mobile, kendo-ui, filtering

I have mobile application by Kendo ui! In mobile listview i try filterable records by DocumentNumber field, but i have the problem when i start entering words datasource always return first records.
    For example if listview have 5 records with DocumentNumber: 11, 22, 33, 14, 15. When i typing 1 it's return 11, 22 , 33, if i typing 33 it's return 11.

```
function taskTodoAssignment() {
    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/Mobile/GetExecuteAssignment',
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false
            }
        },
        parameterMap: function (options) {
            var parameters = {
                take: options.take,
                skip: options.skip,
                pageSize: options.pageSize,
                page: options.page
            };
            return parameters;
        },
        requestStart: function () {
            startLoadingLoader();
        },
        requestEnd: function () {
            kendo.mobile.application.pane.loader.hide();
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (data) {
                return data.Data;
            },
            total: function (data) {
                return data.Count;
            },
            model: {
                id: "TaskId",
                fields: {
                    TaskId: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                    DocumentNumber: { type: "string" },
                    DocumentId: "DocumentId",
                    DocumentDate: { type: "date" },
                    Author: { type: "text" }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 30,
        page: 1,
        serverPaging: true
    });

    $("#task-assignment-list").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        template: $("#task-assignment-template").text(),
        filterable: {
            field: "DocumentNumber",
            operator: "startswith"

        },
        pullToRefresh: true,
        loadMore: true

    });

}
```

Thank you for help! And sorry for my English).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with loadMore setting, try to use latest version of kendo mobile js.

I try with loadMore: false setting, it is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs2y208j/)

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="view" id="mainView" data-init="loadListView" >
      <ul id="listView"></ul>   
</div>

 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="listviewTemplate">    
       <a > <strong > #:Name# </strong>
        <i>  #:DocumentNumber#</i></a>    
 </script>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data:
            [{
                Name: "Name 11",
                DocumentNumber: "11"
            },
            {
                Name: "Name 22",
                DocumentNumber: "22"
            },
            {
                Name: "Name 3",
                DocumentNumber: "3"
            },
            {
                Name: "Name 33",
                DocumentNumber: "33"
            },
            {
                Name: "Name 14",
                DocumentNumber: "14"
            },
            {
                Name: "Name 4",
                DocumentNumber: "4"
            },
            {
                Name: "Name 144",
                DocumentNumber: "144"
            }]
        });

     $("#listView").kendoMobileListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: $("#listviewTemplate").html(),
                filterable: {
                     field: "DocumentNumber",
                     operator: "startswith"
               },
               pullToRefresh: true,
               loadMore: false
     });
```

Comment: Thank you! Your advice helped to me. But load more important function, and it must be! How can i have filtering and load more together???

Comment: I saw your example on JSFiddle, if i set loadMore = true, dataSource doesn't load, but in my application when loadMore= true dataSource loading but filtering always return first record, i will have many records, that's why i need to loadMore and filterable too.

Comment: Can you share JSFiddle link?

Comment: i taked example from kendo demo ui, but they use the server filtering, but i need to client side filtering. This JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g00jk7st/ , when i set loadMore false all is good, but when loadmore = true filtering doesn't work

Comment: Did you see my code in JSFiddle? Do you have any ideas, that how i can deside this! Anyway thank a lot for you help!!!

Comment: I try, but didn't get your require result